# How do I recursively tar+gzip folders with a specific name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zip, recursive

I have a large file structure with multiple nested folders. I would like to tar+gzip up every folder with a specific name and remove the original folder.

In this example the script I hope to have would detect every folder ending in `.abc` and tar+gzip that folder up, removing the original folder and leaving .gz.

```
Main Folder/
    Project 1/
        Prj1FolderA.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
        Prj1FolderB.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
        Prj1FolderC.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
    Project 2/
        Prj2FolderA.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
        Prj2FolderB.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
        Prj2FolderC.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
    Project 3/
        Prj3FolderA.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
        Prj3FolderB.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
        Prj3FolderC.abc/
            ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
    Project 4/
        Another Folder Inside/
            Prj4FolderA.abc/
                ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
            Prj4FolderB.abc/
                ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
            Prj4FolderC.abc/
                ...lots of tiny files and maybe subfolders...
```

After running this script, I would like the folder to look like:

```
Main Folder/
    Project 1/
        Prj1FolderA.abc.tar.gz
        Prj1FolderB.abc.tar.gz
        Prj1FolderC.abc.tar.gz
    Project 2/
        Prj2FolderA.abc.tar.gz
        Prj2FolderB.abc.tar.gz
        Prj2FolderC.abc.tar.gz
    Project 3/
        Prj3FolderA.abc.tar.gz
        Prj3FolderB.abc.tar.gz
        Prj3FolderC.abc.tar.gz
    Project 4/
        Another Folder Inside/
            Prj4FolderA.abc.tar.gz
            Prj4FolderB.abc.tar.gz
            Prj4FolderC.abc.tar.gz
```

This is just an example and the names of the folders may not be exactly as above, nor are they all exactly 2 levels deep. There could be multiple folders in between.

I'm assuming using `find` to do this, but I'm not quite sure how to pass the proper info into `tar` and delete the original folder. Thanks!

Comment: You say "zip" in a few places, but end up with compressed tar files, not zip files. Could you align your wording one way or the other? Thanks!

Comment: Updated - although I'm not sure that clarification is material to the solution. I'd assume one could `tar -czvf` or `zip` the output of a given script, but maybe not! Thanks!

Comment: `zip` creates zip files, while tar & gzip creates .tar.gz files, so it's up to you which one you want to end up with.

Comment: will recursive compress *"Project 4"* when it has *"\*.abc"* in folder name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in `Main Folder`:

```
find . -type d -name '*.abc' -exec sh -c '
    for d; do tar -C "$d" -zcf "$d.tar.gz" . && rm -r "$d"; done
' findsh {} +
```

Although I tested it, I recommend you to test it too. Put an `echo` before `rm`, so if anything goes wrong you do not lose your data.

The inner loop executes `tar` and `rm` (only if `tar` was successful) for found child directories matching the '*.abc' glob pattern.

Comment: I'll definitely be running this in a cloned folder of the data and not on the original dataset. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work quite well. Thank you!